# Calculating coupon yield and continous compounding

Tags: bond, yield, math, compounding

I need to calculate the yield of a 2 year Coupon Bond. Price = 98, Coupon = 3.5, N = 100.

Now when I try to solve this, I arrive at the equation:
$$
98 = 3,5*e^{-y}+103,5*e^{-2*y}
$$
But I can't figure out how to solve this equation for the yield y. I tried with Wolfram Alpha but don't know how to interpret the result. Is my math just too rusty or is my approach wrong?

Comment: You indeed need to solve that equation numerically (say Newton Raphson). WolframAlpha gives you the right solution: $y\approx 0.0446774 \approx 4.5\%$  
 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=98%3D3.5exp%28-y%29%2B103.5exp%28-2y%29

Comment: @KeSchn No. It is just a quadratic equation in disguise!

Comment: @stackoverblown you and ir7 are, of course, absolutely right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $$z = \mathrm{e}^{-y} $$

That way you get a quadratic equation in $z$ (note that $z$ is positive) and then you can get back to $y$ using:

$$ y = -\ln (z) $$